# How can I create a region by uniting some parts and excluding others?

Tags: regions

I've create a region by making a rectangle and two disks and using `RegionUnion`, resulting in a rectangle with two curved sides. Now I want to add an intersecting ellipsoid above it and then remove it (including the area of intersection), or create a "negative" region, so to speak... My aim is to have a region that's like a rounded rectangle with a concave upper side (see image), but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Edit the post and add the code you have used thus far.  Format it with the code button `{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can  use a combination of `RegionUnion` and `RegionDifference`:

```
region = RegionDifference[RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Rectangle[{0,-1},{4,1}], 
    Disk[{4,0}, 1]], Ellipsoid[{2, 1}, {2,1/2}]];

Region[region]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can use `StadiumShape[]` instead: `RegionDifference[StadiumShape[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}}, 1], Ellipsoid[{2, 1}, {2, 1/2}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. thanks; didn't know about `StadiumShape`.